# Push-forward of a smooth function

Tags: differential-geometry, pushforward

I'm confused about the relation between two concepts: the push-forward of a smooth map between two smooth manifolds and the differential of a smooth real-valued function.

Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds and $\varphi :M\to N$ smooth. Then the push-forward of $\varphi$ at $p\in M$ is defined as\begin{align*}\varphi _{*p}:T_pM & \to T_{\varphi (p)}N \\
\varphi _{*p}(X_p)(g) & =X_p(g\circ \varphi )
\end{align*}for $g$ any smooth function on $N$.

On the other hand, for a smooth function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. for the special case $N=\mathbb{R}$, the differential of $f$ at $p$ is defined as\begin{align*}d_pf:T_pM & \to \mathbb{R} \\
d_pf(X_p) & =X_p(f).
\end{align*}Starting from these definitions, can we show that $f_{*p}=d_pf$, or are they different objects?

Comment: Very interesting! So I think what you mean is if we think of $\mathbb R$ as a manifold and $f$ as a mapping to that manifold, then differential of function $f$ is just the push forward?

Comment: If that is what you mean, I agree with you!

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭, yes, this is what I think, but I might be wrong. I tried to prove it but got stuck - hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent space $T_\xi \mathbb R$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ via
$$\alpha_\xi : T_\xi \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,  \alpha_\xi(Z_\xi) = Z_\xi(id), $$
where $id : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, id(x) = x$. Noting that $T_\xi \mathbb R$ has $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \middle\vert_\xi \right\}$ as a basis, we can alternatively specify $\alpha_\xi$ by

$$\alpha_\xi\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \middle\vert_\xi \right) = 1 .$$
The two maps are related by $\alpha_{f(p)} \circ f_{*p} = d_pf$:

$$(\alpha_{f(p)} \circ f_{*p})(X_p) = \alpha_{f(p)}(f_{*p}(X_p)) = f_{*p}(X_p)(id) = X_p(id \circ f) = X_p(f) = d_pf(X_p) .$$

**Update:**

$\alpha_\xi$ is nothing else than the differential $d_\xi id$. It is in fact customary to write $d_\xi id = dx_\xi$. The bases $\{ dx_\xi \}$ of $T^*_\xi \mathbb R$ and $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \middle\vert_\xi \right\}$ of $T_p\mathbb R$ are dual in the usual sense. If $d_pf \ne 0$, then $dx_{f(p)}$ is the only isomorphism $\beta : T_{f(p)}\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $\beta \circ f_{*p} = d_pf$.

More generally, if $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is smooth, then one can show that $d_p(g \circ f) = d_{f(p)}g \circ f_{*p}$. This is a sort of chain rule.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, your $a_{\xi}$ is conventionally written as the basis vector $dx_{\xi}$ of the cotangent space $T_{\xi}^*\mathbb{R}$. And this is exactly what we need: when acting on a vector, it just projects out the vector component, as can be seen from your alternative specification of $a_{\xi}$. I think your answer is correct, but only if the standard chart (the identity) is used on $\mathbb{R}$, viewed as a manifold.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE!

I think you are right, actually, in some books the push forward is just **called differential** even if $N$ is not the real line and the push forward function is denoted by $df$. See even wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)

If both $M,N$ are euclidean spaces then push forward $df$ is just Jacobian of a function at that point.

Your case is special for $M$ is a manifold and $N$ is real line, and there differential and push-forward is also the same.

---

That being said, even if I have called push-forward "differential" for a while, to see the connection in this special case is quite refreshing!

Comment: Thanks! Any hints on how to prove this, starting from the definitions in the question?

Comment: I think in your book, tangent vectors are defined as derivative operators of real-valued functions? (there are other formulations of tangent vector)

Comment: I think the stucking point in this formulation is that in the first definition, the output of $f_{*p}$ will be a vector (operator) in the tangent space of real line at $f(p)$ in the 2nd definition, the output of $df$ will be a number.

Comment: You can think of the output of $df$ as still living in the tangent space of real line. then you can define $d_pf(g)=X_p(g\circ f)$ then it will be the exact same definition as 1.

Comment: Yes, I view tangent vectors as derivative operators. Indeed, the push-forward maps to the tangent space of the real line, but this is isomorphic to the real line itself. So it could be viewed as mapping to the reals, like _df_. I will give it fresh try tomorrow :)

Comment: I can confirm, they are the same. Depending on what you want to do, both names have their virtue. Of course it is a differential in the sense of a linear approximation. On the other hand, viewing it as push-forward, acting on the single tangent spaces by the tangent map, turns $T$ into some kind a functor (up to quite a few details).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: $f_{*p}$ and $d_p f$ (as defined in the question) are different but closely related objects.

As pointed out by Binxu Wang 王彬旭 in one of the comments, $f_{*p}$ maps to $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$, whereas as $d_p f$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., they map to isomorphic (as vector spaces) but not identical targets. Formally,
\begin{equation}
f_{*p}(\cdot) = d_pf(\cdot) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)_{f(p)},
\end{equation}
where $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)_{f(p)} \in T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ is the basis vector induced by the (trivial) chart $y = id_N$ on $N = \mathbb{R}$. In other words, $d_pf(X_p) \in \mathbb{R}$ is the *component* of the vector $f_{*p}(X_p) \in T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the basis induced by the chart $y = id_N$.

But of course, by virtue of the isomorphism $c \mapsto c \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)_{f(p)}$ between $\mathbb{R}$ and $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$, we can consider $d_pf(X_p)$ and $f_{*p}(X_p)$ the same, **up to isomorphism**, for any $X_p \in T_pM$.